# Trigger function on field change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to trigger a function if a flag variable is changed. I read about `ngOnChanges` only works with `@Input` whereas I have a variable.

```
isFormCompleted: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.checkComplete();
}

checkComplete() {
  /**
  * Checks if all conditions are valid and then turns the flag variable to true
  **/
  this.isFormCompleted = true;
}
```

Now I want to fire a function as soon as the flag variable is changed to `true`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rxjs for that, creating a `Subject` which is a stream that you can subscribe on when it changes. Angular should have the packages by default

```
isFormCompleted$: Subject = new Subject<boolean>(false);

ngOnInit() {
  this.isFormCompleted$.subscribe({
    // Here you can add your callback and do with the changing value whatever you want
    next: (v) => console.log(`value: ${v}`)
  });
}

checkComplete() {
  this.isFormCompleted$.next(true);
}
```

This will always be executed when the subject changes its value.
You can trigger it by calling:

```
this.isFormCompleted$.next(true);
```

Documentation: https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject

Answer (score 1):

Using getters and setters:

```
private _isFormCompleted: boolean = false;

get isFormCompleted(): boolean {
  return this._isFormCompleted;
}

set isFormCompleted(value: boolean) {
  this._isFormCompleted = value;
  if (this._isFormCompleted) {
    this.functionCall();
  }
}
```

Comment: Slight change: Add a check since it should only be called on true.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way also.

```
isFormCompleted: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.checkComplete();
}

checkComplete() {

  if (this.isFormCompleted) {
      this.isFormCompleted = !this.isFormCompleted
   }
     
}
```